# Transform repetitive JQuery code into clean code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this code but I tought it was too repetitive, anyone has an idea how I could do that? When a upload a new image, I want a new image box to show up. My solution works, but what if I would like to have 1000 new images? I can't just type one at the time. What could I do to optimise this problem?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_1">
        <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
        <div class="upload-options">
            <label>
                <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image1" data-show='box_image_2' name="IgniteFormObject.Image1" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_2">
        <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
        <div class="upload-options">
            <label>
                <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image2" data-show='box_image_3' name="IgniteFormObject.Image2" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_3">
        <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
        <div class="upload-options">
            <label>
                <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image3" data-show='box_image_4' name="IgniteFormObject.Image3" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_4">
        <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
        <div class="upload-options">
            <label>
                <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image4" data-show='box_image_5' name="IgniteFormObject.Image4" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_5">
        <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
        <div class="upload-options">
            <label>
                <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image5" name="IgniteFormObject.Image5" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

When an image is uploaded, this JQuery is called.

```
$('#image1').change(function (ev) {
    $("#box_image_2").show();
});

$('#image2').change(function (ev) {
    $("#box_image_3").show();
});

$('#image3').change(function (ev) {
    $("#box_image_4").show();
});

$('#image4').change(function (ev) {
    $("#box_image_5").show();
});
```

Comment: show your markup structure.  Seems weird to me you have image1 > box2

Comment: can you post the entire code? with html  i am actually trying to picture out how the change being triggered

Comment: Yes, you can create loops with counters and all that but I think there is a smarter way using selectors,  depending on your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use classes like this:

```
$('.image').change(function (ev) {
    $(this).next(".box_image").show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data` attribute and multiple selector. In the data attribute pass the `id` of the element which you want to show & on change get that attribute

```js
$('#image1,#image2,#image3,#image4').on('change', function(ev) {
  let toShow = $(this).data('show');
  console.log(toShow);
  // $('#'+toShow).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='image1' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_2'>
<input id='image2' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_3'>
<input id='image3' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_4'>
<input id='image4' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_5'>
```

You can also use wildcard selector where `id` begins with `image`

```js
$('input[id^="image"]').on('change', function(ev) {
  let toShow = $(this).data('show');
  console.log(toShow);
  // $('#'+toShow).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='image1' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_2'>
<input id='image2' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_3'>
<input id='image3' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_4'>
<input id='image4' type='checkbox' data-show='box_image_5'>
```

Comment: It works! But what if I had one hundred images? $('#image1,#image2,#image3 ... #image100').on('change', function(ev) {

Comment: In that case use common class and in jquery use class selector

Comment: And how I would do it with IDs?

Comment: `id` is always unique. You can use wild card selector. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method using for loop.

- Create a `for` loop
- Inside the loop set `change` function to `image${i}`.
- And inside the `change` function call `show()` on `box_image_${i+1}`

I also used [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in my code

```
for(let i = 1;i<=4;i++){
   $(`#image${i}`).change(function (ev) {
      $(`#box_image_${i+1}`).show();
   })
}
```

Comment: that is some nice ecma :)  lurve it!

Comment: @brk  No we don't need `iife` it will work fine without it. Thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

Stick it in a loop?

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    $('#image'+i).change(function (ev) {
        $("#box_image_"+(i+1)).show();
    });

}
```

Comment: You might need parseInt() to get the addition to work.

Comment: you are missing a ) - $("#box_image_" + (i + 1)).show();

Answer (score 0):

Strictly based on your markup and how you had unique ids for each elements...

The key is to retreive that `id` from the parent container and increment by one to show the next.

```js
// Hide all containers except the first, on load (possibly already achieved via CSS)
$("[id^='box_image_']").not(":first").hide();

// Change handler
$("[id^='image']").change(function(ev) {

  // Retreive the index part of the container's id
  var parent_box_image_id = $(this).closest("[id^='box_image_']").attr("id").split("box_image_")[1];
  console.log(parent_box_image_id);
  
  // Increment by one
  parent_box_image_id++;

  // Show the next one!
  $("#box_image_"+parent_box_image_id).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_1">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
          <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image1" data-show='box_image_2' name="IgniteFormObject.Image1" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_2">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image2" data-show='box_image_3' name="IgniteFormObject.Image2" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_3">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image3" data-show='box_image_4' name="IgniteFormObject.Image3" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_4">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image4" data-show='box_image_5' name="IgniteFormObject.Image4" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" id="box_image_5">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" id="image5" name="IgniteFormObject.Image5" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**But there could be another way** to do the same more efficiently... Like squarely forgetting about the ids and use classes... Have a look at this other snippet below. ;)

```js
// Hide all containers except the first, on load (possibly already achieved via CSS)
$(".box_image").not(":first").hide();

// Change handler
$(".image-upload").change(function(ev) {
  $(this).closest(".box_image").next().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box_image" class="box_image">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
          <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="IgniteFormObject[]" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" class="box_image">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="IgniteFormObject[]" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" class="box_image">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="IgniteFormObject[]" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" class="box_image">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="IgniteFormObject[]" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box_image" class="box_image">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="IgniteFormObject[]" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```